# Map and Reduce over Google Sheets data range without custom functions

Tags: google-sheets

In Google sheets, if I want to create the following sentence,

```
A and B, C and D, E and F
```

I can have a column with A, C, and E, next to a column with B, D, and F
and create a third column which concatenates the first column with the second using `=concatenate(A1, " and ", B1)`, shown in the example below

```
|   | a | b | c       |
|---|---|---|---------|
| 1 | A | B | A and B |
| 2 | C | D | C and D |
| 3 | E | F | E and F |
```

And then I can just use `=join(",",C1:C3)`

Is there a way to make the required sentence *without using a third column* and *without using custom functions*, such as `=join(",",map(1:3, concatenate(A, " and ", B)))` which is obviously incorrect syntax and doesn't work.

There is an [ArrayFormula](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?visit_id=1-636585231813658589-996859309&hl=en-GB&rd=1) function which does something related to working over arrays, but I can't figure out how to use it or if it is useful to do what I need.

Comment: As a note, I don't actually need to do this, i'm fine with having an extra column which I can just hide anyway, but i'm just curious to see if it can be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better not to use `CONCATENATE()` here as it doesn't seem to work. Instead just manually join with `&`.

```
=JOIN(", ", ARRAYFORMULA(A1:A3&" and "&B1:B3))
```

If you prefer not to manually bound the columns, you can use `FILTER()`.

```
=JOIN(", ", ARRAYFORMULA(FILTER(A:A, NOT(ISBLANK(A:A)))&" and "&FILTER(B:B, NOT(ISBLANK(B:B)))))
```

Answer (score 5):

`=JOIN(", ",FILTER(A:A & " and " & B:B, A:A<>""))`

Comment: There is a lot of cool stuff in your answer i've never seen before. Thanks! I have no idea what the "<>" does

Comment: @RyanWhite `<>` is Google Sheet's way of saying "not equal to". So `A:A<>""` means, "not equal to an empty string".

Answer (score 0):

Here is the syntax:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(CONCATENATE({A1:A3&" and ", B1:B3&","}))
```